# How to pause a continuously running function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a function run continuously with a single button click and then having another button to pause it process. I'm pretty sure its pushing my function every 3 seconds but how do I stop it? I'm pretty sure I'm using clearInterval wrong and I'm not sure if my thought process for "pausing" the process is right here....

I want the start button to keep pushing my profits function(which returns an number) to my list array. I thought of using setInterval() to basically prevent myself from crashing and give myself all the time in the world to push the pause button.
Here is the bit of code I'm having trouble with:

```
var list = [];
var repeater;
$('#Start').click(function(){   
if(userVal != 20) {
    repeater = list.push(setInterval(function(){profits(userVal)},3000));
     //setInterval(list.push(profits(userVal)), 3000);  
}
});
$('#Pause').click(function(){
repeater = clearInterval(repeater);
return repeater;
});
```

Comment: What is list.push doing?

Comment: Sorry, I just added more detail to my problem. list.push is basically adding in the number made from my profits function to my list array.

Comment: Check the code below.

Answer (score 0):

The function you provide to `setInterval` will run every 3000 ms. Then you can use the return value from `setInterval` to stop it from running by passing it to `clearInterval`.

```
var repeater;
$('#Start').click(function(){   
    if(userVal != 20) {
        repeater = setInterval(function(){
            list.push(profits(userVal));
        },3000);

}
});
$('#Pause').click(function(){
    clearInterval(repeater);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, added in more detail to my problem.

Comment: @Falconeyi is that your intention?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
var list = [];
var repeater;
$('#Start').click(function(){   
if(userVal != 20) {
    repeater = setInterval(function(){
                          var temp = profits(userVal);
                          list.push(temp);
               },3000);
}
});
```

And to pause use `clearInterval()`

```
$('#Pause').click(function(){
    clearInterval(repeater);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` returns a numeric reference for clearing out the interval and not the value you'd expect it to return. Use this instead:

```
var list = [];
var repeater;
$('#Start').click(function(){   
    if(userVal != 20)
        repeater = setInterval(function(){
            list.push(profits(userVal));
        },3000));
});
$('#Pause').click(function(){
    clearInterval(repeater);
    // It's a good idea to set the interval to a false-y value so it can be used to detect if the interval is still active. void 0 just returns undefined
    repeater = void 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` will pause your javascript until you press `"OK"`